# How do I run multiple functions which operate on the same collection, but only traverse the collection once? (clojure, example included)

Tags: clojure, mapping, clojurescript

Bit of a weird one, but I essentially need to run two independent functions on a vector. They both map over the vector, and return a result. If I was to run them one after the other, it would mean going over the collection twice - how would I make it so that I only have to map over the collection once, and can perform both functions? The functions themselves can't be changed as they're used elsewhere independently. I might not be making much sense so an example might be better:

```clj
(defn add-one [xs] (map #(+ % 1) xs))
(defn minus-one [xs] (map #(- % 1) xs))
(def my-xs [1 2 3])
(def result {:added (add-one my-xs) :minused (minus-one my-xs)})
```

So, I'd essentially like to be able to calculate "result" but only have to go over "xs" once. I'm not sure it's at all possible to do this given the functions expect a collection but I thought I'd check in case there was some clojure magic I'm missing :D

EDIT - I could just use inc/dec in this example, but the point is that I need to leverage the functions which operate on a collection, as the actual functions are a lot more complex :)

Comment: that would be `(zipmap [:added :minused] (map (juxt inc dec) my-xs))`. So you map the collection just once, applying 2 functions to every item on each step. This higher order function is created with `juxt`

Comment: Hiya, thanks for that! I think the issue (might) be that the functions themselves are more complex, add-one and minus-one were just examples - so I'd need to use the add-one and minus-one functions (as in, the functions which operate on a collection)

Comment: this makes a sense.. well, in case your function needs to operate on the whole collection, you have no choice, but for traversing it every time, i guess.

Comment: Following up on a previous comment, I think the code should be `(zipmap [:added :minused] (apply map vector (map (juxt inc dec) my-xs)))`

Comment: If all your functions there are `(map ? xs)` you can use juxt and then transpose the result. If your functions just all do something totally different on all `xs`, then this becomes harder to do. You could try to reduce over `xs` and the reducing fn could call your functions (that then also would have to be reducing fns) maybe?

Comment: `inc` and `dec` would be `(singlify add-one)` and `(singlify minus-one)` in my answer, thus it is possible from the collection functions to obtain the single-element functions.

Comment: if `map` can't solve it `reduce` usually can :) why can't you just throw it in one `reduce`?

Comment: @nlloyd It's not always easy to convert an arbitrary sequence function in terms of `reduce`. If you have to treat the sequence functions as black boxes, it's of course impossible. Even when you can look at their implementation, it is not always possible, because `reduce` is not lazy.

Answer (score 3):

There is no general solution. If you have two arbitrary functions which consume a sequence and operate on it in some unknown way to produce a result, you cannot avoid traversing the sequence twice.

For various kinds of constraints on the functions, combinations are possible. You've already seen in the comments how `[(map f xs) (map g xs)]` can be replaced with `(apply map list (map (juxt f g) xs))`; similar kinds of things can be done for consumers with a monoidal structure, like combining min and max, or if they are both just `(fn [xs] (reduce f a xs))`.

Comment: My answer is the general solution. The OP asks for a way to travers a seq `sq` only once. While applying `coll-f` and `coll-g` on `sq`. I introduce a function `singlify` which return a function which takes one argument and apply `coll-f` or `coll-g` on it. So instead of `(coll-f sq)` to take one arg `x` and do `((singlify coll-f) x)` and `((singlify coll-g) x)`. `(singlify coll-f)` is exactly `f` and `(singlify coll-g)` is exactly `g`. So `(map f xs)` = `(map (singlify coll-f) xs)` = `(coll-f xs)`.

Comment: Just notice that mapping the juxtaposition and then transposing doesn't handle correctly an empty sequence.

Comment: @peterpun That's funny, I never noticed that the usual solution for transposing doesn't work on an empty list. You could fix this by writing a `transpose` function that handles empty input specially.

Comment: It's a bit trickier than this if we want the result to always contain a row for every mapped function. Normally transposition has to be its own inverse. Using the usual representation for matrices, given that the transposition of `[[]]`, `[[] []]` etc. is `[]`, what should the transposition of `[]` be?

Comment: To correctly handle emptiness we should use a representation that allows for zero rows and non-zero columns. We should also replace mapping the juxtaposition with something that preserves the information about columns (number of mapped functions) in the case of zero rows (an empty sequence).

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to take the collection functions `add-one` and `minus-one` and make them applicable to one single element:

```
(defn singlify [fun] (fn [x] (first (fun [x]))))

;; now you can do:
((singlify #'add-one) 3)
;; => 4
;; so #'add-one became a function applicable for one element only
;; instead to an entire sequence/collection
;; - well actually we just wrap around the argument x a vector and apply
;; the sequence-function on this `[x]` and then take the result out of the
;; result list/vec/seq by a `first` - so this is not the most performant solution.
;; however, we can now use the functions and get the single-element versions
;; of them without having to modify the original functions.
;; And this solution is generalize-able to all collection functions.
```

Now using the comments' helpful hints, which tell that `juxt` makes it possible to apply two different functions on a sequence while traversing just once through it,
we get

```
(map (juxt (singlify #'add-one) (singlify #'minus-one)) my-xs)
;; => ([2 0] [3 1] [4 2])
```

Using `zipmap` and the helpful lispy idiom `(apply map #'<collector-function> <input-collection>)` to transpose the result list, we can split them into a dict/map with the corresponding
keywords upfront:

```
(zipmap [:added :minused] 
        (apply map vector 
               (map (juxt (singlify #'add-one) 
                          (singlify #'minus-one)) 
                    my-xs)))
;; => {:added [2 3 4], :minused [0 1 2]}
```

#### generalize as a function

We can generalize this as a function which takes a seq of keys, a seq of to-be-applied collection-functions and the to-be-once-only-traversed input seq/collection:

```
;; this helper function applies `juxt` 
;; on the `singlify`-ed versions of the collection-functions:
(defn juxtify [funcs] (apply #'juxt (map #(singlify %) funcs)))

;; so the generalized function is:
(defn traverse-once [keys seq-funcs sq]
  (zipmap keys (apply map vector (map (juxtify seq-funcs) sq))))
```

Using this function, the example case looks like this:

```
(traverse-once [:added :minused] [#'add-one #'minus-one] my-xs)
;; => {:added [2 3 4], :minused [0 1 2]}
```

We can now extend is as we want:

```
(traverse-once [:squared 
                :minused 
                :added] 
               [(fn [sq] (map #(* % %) sq)) 
                #'minus-one 
                #'add-one] 
               my-xs)
;; => {:squared [1 4 9], :minused [0 1 2], :added [2 3 4]}
```

Voila!

Comment: This is not a very general solution at all. As far as I can tell it only works for functions of the form `(fn [xs] (map f xs))`. Try it, for example, with `(fn [xs] (apply + xs))`. Also, while in Common Lisp you need `#'foo` to refer to the function `foo` as a value, in Clojure you just use `foo`.

Comment: That fix doesn't work. This is not a surprise, because as I say what you are trying to do is impossible. The point is that `#(apply + %)` computes the sum of a sequence, whereas your new `singlify` changes it to just be the identity function. Any correct implementation must satisfy the property that `(= {:f (f xs) :g (g xs)} (traverse-once [:f :g] [f g] xs))` - that is precisely what was asked for. No possible definition of `traverse-once` can do this without traversing `xs` twice.

Comment: `((singlify (fn [xs] (apply + xs))) 3)` returns `3` so it works. `traverse-once` does exactly that! Don't you see my example code?

Comment: `(traverse-once [:added :minused] [#'add-one #'minus-one] my-xs)
;; => {:added [2 3 4], :minused [0 1 2]}`

Comment: The trick with `singlify` is - it takes an element and makes it a sequence of length one and applies `f` and `g` on these single element lists - so that you can use them without redefining them for one element case.

Comment: Using `juxt`, `traverse-once` traverses exactly once through a sequence while applying all `juxt`-ed collection functions during its single traverse on each element of the collection - and it collects the results - which are then paired with the correct key word in the resulting map (by using `zipmap`).

Comment: The problem with `(fn [xs] (apply + xs))` is more your problem of udnerstanding.

Comment: `(fn [xs] (apply + xs))` returns just a single number - the sum of the elements of `xs`.

Comment: The original poster however asked for functions which take a sequence and return a sequence - where some operation on each element of `xs` is applied - so retun value must be a list. Your "not working" function is a different kind of function. So I deleted now my "fix" again.

Comment: You haven't solved it for "functions which take a sequence and return a sequence" either - that's a broad category. But the OP actually claims that the relevant functions "both map over the vector". Your solution does work for that case: if we specifically have `(defn f [xs] (map f' xs))`, your `singlify` adequately recovers `f'` from `f`. I didn't read the original question as asking for this, because it's pretty useless: just use `f` instead of `f'`, and combine with `juxt`. But sure, if for some reason this is really the problem, your solution works.

Comment: @amalloy Thanks for the comment. In which case of "function which take a sequence and return a sequence" the `singlify` solution wouldn't work? I mean isn't it obvious that it must be a function which goes through each element of the collection and applies some function on it? Maybe I overlooked sth ...

Comment: There are lots of such functions. For example, `(defn f [xs] (mapcat (fn [x] [x x]]) xs)`. Or `(def g reverse)`. Or `(defn h [xs] [(apply + xs)])`. Or `(defn p [xs] [(count xs)]))`. Genuinely anything at all that isn't just an application of `map`.

Comment: Oh, or maybe the simplest list->list function of all: `(fn [xs] ())`

Answer (score 1):

*The functions themselves can't be changed as they're used elsewhere independently.*

Refactor so that the operations collecting the values are independent of the sequence consumption, then reimplement the sequence consumption functions atop these refactorings (so the existing API is honoured, as that's a hard constraint), and then compose the independent operations as needed to avoid repeated sequence iteration.

In the case that you are consuming an upstream package from outside your organisation, open a dialog about them changing the API to allow for efficient operation in this way.

Any approaches along the lines of digging around the functions such as singlify are likely to break in subtle ways or confuse future maintainers, even assuming that the cost of boxing sequence items in a vector for reconsumption isn't a performance issue.

Comment: True - but what if you have legacy code and you are really not allowed to change existing code and the collection functions are very complicated - let's say state-dependent?

Comment: If we place arbitrary constraints then we can make simple things complex. I'm trying to point out that the constraints are really in people's heads. All code is mutable with enough effort!

Comment: True - one could use decorators? What other efforts one coould do to make code mutable without changing legacy code?

Answer (score 0):

- Traverse the sequence once, using `juxt` to calculate all the results
  you want for each element - call it the `base` sequence.
- Return a map of sequences, each of which selects its own element from
  the elements of the `base` sequence. This is transposing on demand.

Thus:

```
(defn one-pass-maps [fn-map]
  (let [fn-vector (apply juxt (vals fn-map))]
    (fn [coll]
      (let [base (map fn-vector coll)]
        (zipmap (keys fn-map) (map (fn [n] (map #(% n) base)) (range)))))))
```

For example,

```
((one-pass-maps {:inc inc, :dec dec}) (range 10))
=> {:inc (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10), :dec (-1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)}
```

All the traversals are lazy. The `base` sequence is only realized as far as any transposed sequence travels. But if one sequence is realized up to - say - the fifth element, they all are.

Answer (score 0):

A helpful general strategy is to express a function in an algebraic style and use various algebraic laws to optimize it. In this answer, I will focus on the case where the sequence processing can be expressed through `reduce` or `transduce`, something that maybe captures the notion of eagerly traversing a sequence, and use some "tupling laws". For brevity and clarity I will omit the handling of early termination (via `reduced`), a functionality that isn't too hard to add.

First of all, I will use the modified versions of `reduce` and `transduce` shown below, which have some more desirable properties for the present case:

```clj
(defn reduce
  ([f coll] (reduce f (f) coll))
  ([f init coll] (clojure.core/reduce f init coll)))

(defn transduce [xf f & args]
  (let [f (xf f)]
    (f (apply reduce f args))))
```

I will also introduce polymorphic versions of `juxt`, `map` and `map-indexed`, which operate on vectors and maps:

```clj
(defprotocol JuxtMap
  (juxt* [fs])
  (map* [coll f])
  (map-indexed* [coll f]))

(extend-protocol JuxtMap

  clojure.lang.IPersistentVector
  (juxt* [fs]
    (fn [& xs]
      (into [] (map #(apply % xs)) fs)))
  (map* [coll f]
    (into [] (map f) coll))
  (map-indexed* [coll f]
    (into [] (map-indexed f) coll))

  clojure.lang.IPersistentMap
  (juxt* [fs]
    (fn [& xs]
      (into {} (map (juxt key (comp #(apply % xs) val))) fs)))
  (map* [coll f]
    (into {} (map (juxt key (comp f val))) coll))
  (map-indexed* [coll f]
    (into {} (map (juxt key (partial apply f))) coll)))

(letfn [(flip [f] #(f %2 %1))]
  (def map* (flip map*))
  (def map-indexed* (flip map-indexed*)))
```

Now we can create two functions, `juxt*-rf` and `juxt*-xf`, which satisfy the following "tupling laws", denoting composition by `o` and assuming that `reduce`, `transduce` and `map*` are curried in their first parameter and the first two don't receive an `init`:

- `reduce o juxt*-rf = juxt* o map*(reduce)`
- `transduce o juxt*-xf = juxt* o map*(transduce)`

Here they are:

```clj
(def juxt*-rf
  (comp
    juxt*
    (partial map-indexed*
      (fn [i f]
        (fn
          ([] (f))
          ([acc] (f (acc i)))
          ([acc x] (f (acc i) x)))))))

(def juxt*-xf
  (comp
    (partial comp juxt*-rf)
    juxt*))
```

Finally, let's see `juxt*-xf` in action:

```clj
(defn average [coll]
  (->> coll
       (transduce
         (juxt*-xf [identity (map (constantly 1))])
         +)
       (apply /)))

(average [1 2 3])
;result: 2

(defn map-many [fs coll]
  (transduce
    (juxt*-xf (map* map fs))
    conj
    coll))

(map-many {:inc inc, :dec dec} [1 2 3])
;result: {:inc [2 3 4], :dec [0 1 2]}

(transduce
  (juxt*-xf {:transp (juxt*-xf (map* map [first second]))
             :concat cat})
  conj
  [[1 11] [2 12] [3 13]])
;result: {:transp [[1 2 3] [11 12 13]], :concat [1 11 2 12 3 13]}
```